# What gives? White space page where results should be produced

Tags: php, mysql

I have code trying to check if a value exists in a coulmn, but it only produces white space even though the query by itself produces right output in phpMyAdmin.  My code is then called through using include_once in another page. What am I doing wrong?  The only output I receive is a blank white page (if run direct) and otherwise another blank white page (if used by inclusion using include_once in another page).  I have tried using echo, return, etc also to no avail.  PLEASE TAKE NOTE:  I am aware that I should be using mysqli or pdo, but this is a mod on a LEGACY site and app; so please refrain from notations on that and also the antiquated html tag usage.  ALSO NOTE:  the $_Session[AccountSession] has been previously (in another page) cleaned using preventative measures for SQL injection, so again please refrain from notations on that.

My current code is:

```
<?php 

// Start the session
session_start ();
ob_start();

// Include the necessary classes
include_once("../../includes/dbaccess.class.php");

// Connect to the database
$db = new dbAccess();
if (!$db->connect()) die("Not connected");

$lspresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE Account='$_SESSION[AccountSession]' AND LSP='1'");
if(mysql_num_rows($lspresult) == 0) {
     // row not found
} else {
    // row found
    <<<EOO

    <tr margin-left="40px">
        <td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="80%">
            <input type="checkbox" valign="top" name="do_LSP" id="do_LSP" value="1" onClick="this.form.do_SexOffend.checked=1">
            <label for="do_LSP"> <font color="blue"><b>La State Police Background Check</b></font> 
                </label>
        </td>
        <td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

EOO;
}

?>
```

EDITED:  After the suggestion to test my assumptions provided by Bill Karwin (*thank you), I made some appropriate mods and now the following code works when called directly, but not when included as included page.  The working (directly called) code is:

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start ();
ob_start();

// Include the necessary classes
include_once("../../includes/dbaccess.class.php");

// Connect to the database
$db = new dbAccess();
if (!$db->connect()) die("Not connected");

$lspresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE Account='$_SESSION[AccountSession]' AND LSP='1'");
if(mysql_num_rows($lspresult) == 0) {
     // row not found
} else { ?>
        <tr margin-left="40px">
        <td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="80%">
            <input type="checkbox" valign="top" name="do_LSP" id="do_LSP" value="1" onClick="this.form.do_SexOffend.checked=1">
            <label for="do_LSP"> <font color="blue"><b>La State Police Background Check</b></font> 
            </label>
        </td>
        <td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

The include is inside a class, then a function, then inside of: 
    <<

```
<!-- some html code content here -->

<?php include_once("./lspcheck.php");?>

<!-- some more html code content here -->

EOO;
```

Does an include_once need special treatment when placed inside of html code wrapped as such above?

Comment: Did you forget to `echo` that chunk of html (or whatever it is you use in php to render content)?

Comment: `<font>` and layout tables. That HTML is stuck in the 20th century. :(

Comment: Why are you using the long-deprecated `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Comment: If you guys would... please see my comments in the original post.  I explained that I am modd'ing a legacy app.  That is why the usage of mysql library and why their is antiquated html code.

Comment: QUOTE:  I have tried using echo, return, etc also to no avail. I am aware that I should be using mysqli or pdo, but this is a mod on a legacy site; so please refrain from notations on that. Also, the $_Session[AccountSession] has been previously cleaned using preventative measures for SQl injection, so again please refrain from notations on that. ENDQUOTE

Comment: That being said, can someone please help me out here?

Comment: ...and  ADyson you are wrong about mysql library being discontinued many years ago...  mysql libary, yes, was removed completely from PHPv7+; however, it is still valid, still used in thousands of websites across the web utilizing version PHP version less than 7.

Comment: Yes it's still used, but no it's not still valid. Development and patching on it was stopped many years before it was actually removed from the code. It could have all sorts of vulnerabilities (including to things that were not thought of or known before the development stopped), and no-one is maintaining it to try and fix them. That's why it's a bad idea to continue using it. As well as the fact it categorically doesn't support things like parameters that are known to make your application safer. If you don't have a plan to migrate away from it, you're neglecting your users and customers.

Comment: Use of PHP<7 is not an excuse to continue with something that was deprecated and discontinued long before that, especially when the better alternatives have been available for years and years, since early versions of PHP5, and people have been advocating their use for all that time. Change is not cheap or always simple, I'm not naive about that - I've done the migration myself - but it's 100% necessary to have any confidence that you are keeping your application and its data secure.

Comment: ADyson: inattempts at maintaining civility AND to keep our focus in and of this post 'o mine. . .  .   I'll say AGAIN, I KNOW all about all that.  However,, the customer is 99.9% of the time right as they say and I CAN't W/O THEIR PERMISSION AND APPROVAL waste neither time nor energies migratingt away from MySql library in PHP AND from transitioning the entire code base and source to PHP v7+  My orders are much different AND I have already anyway made client aware.  Choice was NOT to fix nor expended funds for same.   Now, staying with the purpose and focus of this port 'o mine......

Comment: Also, @Adyson:  In order for the overall result purposes be established or in\that this post and our comments thereafter do NOT confuse

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you start testing your assumptions.

For example, when accessing an associative array, you should use quotes around the key, otherwise PHP thinks you're using a PHP constant, not a string. If no constant by that name is defined, it'll default to a string of the same spelling, but if a constant *is* defined, its value is used.

```
$account = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['AccountSession']);
error_log("AccountSession = '$account'");
```

Likewise, output some debugging for each step to make sure it is what you think it is. Use `error_log()` because that'll output to the http server error log instead of your HTML output ob buffer.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE Account='{$account}' AND LSP='1'"
error_log("SQL = '$sql'");
$lspresult = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($lspresult) == 0) {
     error_log("Row not found");
     // row not found
} else {
     error_log("Row was found");
    // row found
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll do that.  Appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: I edited my "question" including mods made relative to your suggestion.  Can you please step me through this next obstacle?  Thank you.

Comment: You don't seem to have changed anything relative to my suggestions.

Comment: yes, doing as you stated showed me that I needed to separate out the html code by closing php before and then reopening after